# Installing PHP_codesniffer with Pear and MAMP Pro on OSX

Tags: macos, pear, phpcodesniffer

I've tried all kinds of fixes to get php_codesniffer working with OSX and Pear and am having no luck. The installation works, the scripts are there, but when I run, for example, `phpcs -h`, nothing happens.

I am doing the following to install and try to run:

```
chris@DEATHSTAR:~$ pear clear-cache
reading directory /var/folders/r5/3s2lsmc10zj07nw56xbx1k1m0000gn/T//pear/cache
14 cache entries cleared
chris@DEATHSTAR:~$ pear install php_codesniffer
Unknown remote channel: pear.phpunit.de
Did not download optional dependencies: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHP_Timer, use --alldeps to download automatically
pear/PHP_CodeSniffer can optionally use package "channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHP_Timer"
downloading PHP_CodeSniffer-1.4.6.tgz ...
Starting to download PHP_CodeSniffer-1.4.6.tgz (402,882 bytes)
.................................................................................done: 402,882 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/PHP_CodeSniffer-1.4.6
chris@DEATHSTAR:~$ which phpcs
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/phpcs
chris@DEATHSTAR:~$ phpcs -h
chris@DEATHSTAR:~$
```

The PHP directory is correct in Pear config:

```
chris@DEATHSTAR:~/.vim$ pear config-show | grep php_bin
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php
```

Not sure what else I can do to troubleshoot?

Possible related note: PHP Mass Detector does essentially the same thing...it installs correctly, but running it seemingly does nothing as well!

Answer (score 1):

I think the phpcs binary file is not inside your $PATH. Use the follow steps to figure out if this is true:

1. Call the codesniffer on your command line with entering the full path:
   `$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/phpcs -h`
   If you get the help output then proceed with step 2. If not something else is broken in your setup.
2. Export this path to $PATH:
   `$ export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/phpcs`
3. Call the CodeSniffer like you try before:
   `$ phpcs -h`
4. To make this change permanent you need to insert the command from 2. into you .profile/.bashrc/.zshrc or whatever you use as a shell

Comment: Something is definitely broken in my config.

$ which pear
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.19/bin/pear
$ which phpcs
$ pear install php_codesniffer
pear/php_codesniffer is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.5.2
install failed
$ locate phpcs
/Users/mgifford/pear/bin/phpcs
/Users/mgifford/pear/bin/scripts/phpcs-svn-pre-commit
/Users/mgifford/pear/phpcs
/Users/mgifford/pear/scripts/phpcs-svn-pre-commit
$ /Users/mgifford/pear/bin/phpcs -h

Warning: include_once(PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php): ... 

Nothing relevant in $ pear config-show